# navigating page results from an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, twilio

I have a view in a rails app where I am showing a user their latest 50 recordings via the Twilio API.

While page_size returned is capped at 50 results, the API returns URIs to the next, previous, first and last pages of the returned list. (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information)

I'm having trouble understanding how I link to these results at the bottom of that table such that when a user clicks 'next page', the page refreshes and the table populates with the next 50 recordings.

Here is a look at the table:

```
<% @recordings.list({}).each do |recording| %>

  <tr>
     <td><%= recording.sid %></td>
     <td><%= recording.duration %>sec</td>
     <td><%= recording.from %></td>
     <td><%= recording.to %></td>
 </tr>

<% end %>

<%= link_to "next page", "?" %>
```

I can see the "next_page_uri" in the response when I am looking at it in the rails console, I'm just unsure of how I "link" to it to populate the table.

Edit**
I made a request via their API explorer to show the output (in JSON) - I shortened the page results to one for the request so it would be easier to read.

```
{
      "first_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12/Recordings.json?AccountSid=ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12&Page=0&CSRF=1388959981-bedd066b4f6119c70465377bb8bc012a72ea7b13be683a0819b065aa9db559c7&PageSize=1&Format=json",
      "num_pages": 178,
      "previous_page_uri": null,
      "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12/Recordings.json?Format=json&AccountSid=ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12&PageSize=1&CSRF=1388959981-bedd066b4f6119c70465377bb8bc012a72ea7b13be683a0819b065aa9db559c7",
      "page_size": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "recordings": [
        {
          "sid": "RE54146168533b781c0cbbaa9ada009d29",
          "account_sid": "ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12",
          "call_sid": "CAd5396192caf4c5f73a45c5026b7156a5",
          "duration": "19",
          "date_created": "Fri, 03 Jan 2014 15:32:36 +0000",
          "api_version": "2010-04-01",
          "date_updated": "Fri, 03 Jan 2014 15:32:36 +0000",
          "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12/Recordings/RE54146168533b781c0cbbaa9ada009d29.json"
        }
      ],
      "next_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12/Recordings.json?AccountSid=ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12&Page=1&CSRF=1388959981-bedd066b4f6119c70465377bb8bc012a72ea7b13be683a0819b065aa9db559c7&PageSize=1&Format=json",
      "end": 0,
      "total": 178,
      "last_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12/Recordings.json?AccountSid=ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12&Page=177&CSRF=1388959981-bedd066b4f6119c70465377bb8bc012a72ea7b13be683a0819b065aa9db559c7&PageSize=1&Format=json",
      "page": 0
    }
```

Twilio Controller -

```
@account_sid = @user.twilio_account_sid
@auth_token = @user.twilio_auth_token

# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account

@recordings = @subaccount.recordings
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `page` param in your URL, and the "Next" button is a link to the current page with the `page` param incremented.  Then on the server you make the request to

```
"/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12/Recordings.json?AccountSid=ACb76fd7689d66a37b3defd366bc3caf12&Page=#{param[:page]}&CSRF=1388959981-bedd066b4f6119c70465377bb8bc012a72ea7b13be683a0819b065aa9db559c7&PageSize=1&Format=json"
```

Comment: That occurred to me, but I'm still unclear as to how the recordings.list call will know to use the new data in rendering the table?

Comment: You never told us how you're populating the `@recordings` variable in the first place.  Presumably you're computing it from the response to a request to the Twilio API.  If so, then just do that again with the updated URI.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up Amit.  I've added the Twilio request to my question.  Are you suggesting the @recordings will repopulate with the updated data on page refresh?